# Will the JVM / Compiler optimize a simple super method call?

Tags: java, methods, super

So if I have

```
public void methodName() {
super.methodName();
}
```

How will the Compiler / JVM handle this? Will it be treated the same as if the override never happened assuming the signatures are identical? I want to put this bit of code in as a clarification of intent so that folks don't wonder why `hashCode()` wasn't implemented in the same class as `equals()`

If it makes a difference to the system though, maybe not.

Comment: You ask that as if there is one version of one JVM implementation on only one target platform. There is one thing to Java that is generic among any iteration of it: the fact that it is designed to allow you to not care, the JVM takes care of it for you. If you must pry, you're in for some byte code disassembling and profiling.

Comment: ...on every platform the JVM runs on for a complete answer? Ouch.

Comment: This call can be optimized like you want it to by pure inlining, and all JVMs I know do heavy inlining. So it is an educated guess that this will be optimized as you would expect.

Comment: `I want to put this bit of code in as a clarification of intent` - if somehow possible, I'd try to move this kind of descriptive code into a sub interface (given you can implement the class hierarchy as a hierarchy of interfaces). This is very often done e.g. in the Java `Collection` API, when a subinterface provides more detailed information about the behavior of individual methods. That way no unnecessary code needs to be in the concrete subclasses and you will still get all the necessary information from the Javadoc.

Comment: Makes sense but you are not taking into account the fact that Sonar is going to complain about it and then we have to do the Sonar Circus. <Queue Circus Music> I'm trying to get the rules edited now but that is owned by CM so it means formality. IMHO, CM should keep their stuff on an entirely different Jenkins instance than ours so that we can have reasonable access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, often the question “Can the JVM / Compiler optimize this particular method call?” is different from “Will it optimize said call?”, but your actual question is a different one.

Your real question is “Should I worry about the performance of this delegation call?” and that’s much easier to answer as it is a clear “No, don’t worry”.

First of all, regardless of whether a method invocation gets special treatment by the optimizer or not, the cost of a single invocation is negligible. It really doesn’t matter.

The reason, why optimizations of invocations are ever discussed, is not that the invocation itself is so expensive, but that inlining a method invocation enables follow-up optimizations by analyzing the caller’s code and the callee’s code as a unit. Obviously, this isn’t relevant to the trivial code of your overriding method. It only becomes relevant if the optimizer is going to take the caller’s context into account and if such an inlining operation happens, that single delegation step is indeed no match to the optimizer. The result of such an optimization will indeed be “as if the override never happened” (which applies to a lot of not so trivial scenarios as well).

But if that ever happens, depends on several surrounding conditions, including the question whether the code is a performance relevant hot spot. If not, it might happen that a call doesn’t get optimized, but that still shouldn’t bother you, because, well, it’s not performance relevant then.